# Parametrization of Bumpy Tourus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, parametrization

> Find a parametrization of the bumpy torus, given as the set of
>   points which have distance 5+2cos(7θ) from the circle
>   <10cos(θ), 10sin(θ), 0>, where θ is the angle occurring in cylindrical
>   and spherical coordinates.

So, I've calculated the distance *r* from a point to the z-axis as *r* = (10+(5+2cos(7θ))cos(ϕ). However, I'm having issues translating it back to Cartesian coordinates. Does anyone want to give me a hand here?